# List of elements in join table without match

Tags: r, outer-join

When performing a left outer join, how do I find the elements from the right table that didn't find a match in the left table? Do you just do a right outer join and discard elements with a match to be left with the elements from the right table without a match?

That seems like a sketchy solution, so is there a more elegant way of finding the orphaned elements in the right table?

Comment: After a left join, there is no immediate way to find the un-matched elements. You can use `anti_join` to find what isn't found, in a separate merge operation.

Comment: OR you can do a `full_join` and find the elements that have missing data in the left-data's fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a `left_join` is *done*, you cannot find out what wasn't matched. As Petr suggested in that answer, you can subsequently use `anti_join` to find what doesn't match.

Another technique (that only requires one merge operation) is to do a full join and filter on elements unique to the left and to the right to see what is missing.

Using datasets used in the examples of `full_join`:

```r
full_join(band_members, band_instruments)
# Joining, by = "name"
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   name  band    plays 
#   <chr> <chr>   <chr> 
# 1 Mick  Stones  <NA>  
# 2 John  Beatles guitar
# 3 Paul  Beatles bass  
# 4 Keith <NA>    guitar
```

In this example, one can approximate the left-join with `filter(!is.na(band))` and right-join with `filter(!is.na(plays))`, and finally one can get the second frame's unmatched elements with `filter(is.na(plays))`.

In this example, it's "clear" since there were no `NA` values before the merge. If there is no column that is known to never be `NA` (in either or both frames), then you can add one with low-cost. For instance `mutate(band_members, orig=TRUE)` (and same for `band_instruments`) will give you solid "known" columns.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [`anti_join()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html) in this way:

```
right_table %>% anti_join(left_table)
```

This filters only rows in the `right_table`, which don't match any row in the `left_table`.